# Get Bluetooth Address on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, mac-address

I would like to get the Bluetooth address of the current Android device.

Here's the context, I have an app that scans for Bluetooth devices and should tell the user if they have been in contact with a specific device. The way I identify devices is by their Bluetooth address, however using the `getAddress()` method, I don't seem to get the correct address, on some devices it returns the network MAC address, on some others it jus returns a certain address that I don't know where it got it from.

Any ideas over how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the other devices are 'discoverable'.
This is from the android developer guide:

> However, a nearby Bluetooth device responds to a discovery request
> only if it is currently accepting information requests by being
> discoverable. If a device is discoverable, it responds to the
> discovery request by sharing some information, such as the device's
> name, its class, **and its unique MAC address**. Using this information,
> the device that is performing the discovery process can then choose to
> initiate a connection to the discovered device.

Comment: Talking about discovery. Any ideas on how I can get the device to be eternally discoverable, or at least when a certain function is running?